# How to print out for loop of table values in flask/python

Tags: python, flask

So I have two arrays of data. One has a list of bot_ids, The other has names.

Im trying to print out the arrays to an html page in table format.

I want the html to have one row with the names and then another row with the bot_id.

I tried doing two loops. One loop is the for names, the other is for the ids. I also tried doing doing one loop with both bot_ids and names but It

```
names = []
bot_ids = []
for item in data['response']:
    name = item['name']
    bot_id = item['bot_id']
    names.append(name)
    bot_ids.append(bot_id)

print names
print bot_ids

return render_template("ids.html", data=bot_ids, theNames=names) for 2 separate arrays so it wont work. 


<table>
 <tr>
  <th> Names </th>
  <th> Bot Ids </th>
 </tr>
    {%for names in theNames%}
    {%for ids in data%}
  <tr>
    <td> {{names}} </td>
    <td> {{ids}} </td>
  </tr>
  {%endfor%}
  {%endfor%}

</table>
```

The problem that I ran into was that it would print out DUPLICATES of the ids and names. The html ended up looking like this:

```
Names   Bot Ids
Johnny Five 240b08e530d42f286f30a75379
Johnny Five 64395a02a9382796f7cd7616ef
Johnny Five 42aacdb69615721d68c31d71c0
Johnny Five d45a95b6bbb344639104fd6a3a
Johnny Five 240b08e530d42f286f30a75379
Johnny Five 64395a02a9382796f7cd7616ef
Johnny Five 42aacdb69615721d68c31d71c0
Johnny Five d45a95b6bbb344639104fd6a3a
suck ya mom 240b08e530d42f286f30a75379
suck ya mom 64395a02a9382796f7cd7616ef
suck ya mom 42aacdb69615721d68c31d71c0
suck ya mom d45a95b6bbb344639104fd6a3a
The goat    240b08e530d42f286f30a75379
The goat    64395a02a9382796f7cd7616ef
The goat    42aacdb69615721d68c31d71c0
The goat    d45a95b6bbb344639104fd6a3a
```

I want it to only print out the elements once each time but its producing many duplicates

the first code fence IS whats running in the app.py file
The second part is what is in the html file.

Comment: Instead of passing in two lists of data what you should pass to the template is the response data object and then use 
```
{%for item in response_data %}
  <tr>
    <td> {{item.name}} </td>
    <td> {{item.id}} </td>
  </tr>
  {%endfor%}
```

Comment: @eodgooch Oh snap I'll try that. Thank you!!

Comment: @eodgooch You are a God damn genius thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are doing 2 loops of the same length. You should zip them together and do it in one loop:

```
  {%for id, name in zip(data, theNames)%}
<tr>
  <td> {{id}} </td>
  <td> {{name}} </td>
</tr>
  {%endfor%}
```

The indentation may need fixing but that should work.